# Segue back to TableView at selected cell row

Tags: iphone, ios, segue

I have a UItableView that segues to a different view controller. I'm using a UITapGestureRecognizer that segues back to the tableView. This segue works, but I would like it to segue back to the tableView at the originally selected table row. How do I accomplish this?

Edit: Edited code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  {

 appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(appDelegate.testCGPoint));

 [self.tableView setContentOffset:appDelegate.testCGPoint animated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {

   appDelegate.testCGPoint = [self.tableView contentOffset];

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the content offset of the table view into a value. 
    float tableContentOffset; 
Then later, save the offset into that float.
Finally, when you need to set the content offset of the table view, 
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,tableContentOffset) animated:YES];

Comment: This code should go in the view controller's viewWillAppear: method.

Comment: I used CGPoint instead of float, and it is not working for me. Although, I'm a novice, so I may be doing more than one thing incorrectly here. Please see edited code above.

Comment: Please look at my second answer! Your problem may lie within the accessing of the tableContentOffset variable!

Answer (score 0):

So, in your code, you've created a CGPoint. However, the creation existed within the method prepareForSegue. Thus, you cannot access the point outside of the method! A solution to this is to create the CGPoint in the header file. 
CGPoint tableContentOffest;
Then in your prepareForSegue method, all you have to do is SET the table's offset value. Don't create a new CGPoint. 
Additionally, in your code [vc.tableView setContentOffset:_tableContentOffset animated:YES]; you would want to set it with [vc.tableView setContentOffset:tableContentOffset animated:YES]; and not _tableContentOffset.
Hope this helped!

Comment: Do I have to create `CGPoint tableContentOffset` in a ViewController class or something? The compiler is not recognizing the variable in DetailViewController. I have `CGPoint tableContentOffset` set in my ViewController header @interface{}

Comment: Ok, I kinda have it working now. I was completely misunderstanding the  `self.tableView...` part and now I realize I don't need any if this code in my detailViewController. Everything is set in my main VC. However, I couldn't get it working when I put `CGPoint tableContentOffset in my header file. It seemed like it was getting reset or not setting when the view reappeared. Instead, I set CGPoint in AppDelegate and called it in my VC. This seems to work, but I'm not sure why I was unable to use your method.

Comment: Also, it works now, but setContentOffset is delayed. I have edited my code above again. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Fixed the delay. Just had to set `animated:NO`